# Passing variable to bash script from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I'm trying to pass variables from python script to bash, but not able to invoke the variable in bash.

```py
clustername=sys.argv[1]

subprocess.check_call("/data/path/script.sh '%s'" % str(clustername), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

And tried to print `subprocess` output, but was not able to print.
It is returning only code

Below is the bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
clustername=$clustername # invoking from pythonscript
------
---Some logic -
---end
```

Comment: What's in `script.sh`?

Comment: @bereal, edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in the `bash` file you are supposed to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
clustername=$1 # invoking from pythonscript
```

to get the command line arguments passed into the script.

Secondly, using `check_call()`, you will not be able to catch the output from the `bash` script. You will need to use `subprocess.run()` or `subprocess.check_output()` or something similar to achieve that.

You can try doing the following:

```
import sys
import subprocess

clustername=sys.argv[1]
print(subprocess.run(["/data/path/script.sh", str(clustername)], universal_newlines=True).stdout)
```

`check_call()` will only return the return code and not the stdout. You can also try `check_output()` if you want to see the output.

You can also do the following using `check_output`:

```
print(subprocess.check_output(["/data/path/script.sh", str(clustername)], universal_newlines=True))
```

###### Edit

Removed `shell=True` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: You really want to avoid the unnecessary `shell=True` here, too. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: If you only want to display the output to the user, capturing it so you can then print it is just inefficient. If you don't pass a `stdout=` keyword argument, the default behavior is for the subprocess to print directly to standard output, outside of Python's view or control.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the input. I will update the answer to reflect these changes. I'm not very thorough with Python and hence bound to write inefficient code.

Comment: @tripleee although if I remove the `shell=True`, I'm getting `FileNotFoundError`. Any idea why?

Comment: Like the linked question's answers reveal, you need to refactor to pass a list if you omit `shell=True`, i.e. `subprocess.run(["/data/path/script.sh", str(clustername)], ...)`